How to install a specific LaTeX package version without messing the other LaTeX packages already installed from texlive-latex-* DEB packages up
The ptex-jtex DEB package containing the multicol.sty LaTeX package has been removed from the multiverse : ptex-jtex.
EDIT0: I had already installed the texlive-latex-extra or texlive-latex-base packages.
Here is what I have and did :
$ dpkg -l | grep texlive-
ii  texlive-base                          2023.20240207-1                         all          TeX Live: Essential programs and files
ii  texlive-binaries                      2023.20230311.66589-9build3             amd64        Binaries for TeX Live
ii  texlive-fonts-recommended             2023.20240207-1                         all          TeX Live: Recommended fonts
ii  texlive-latex-base                    2023.20240207-1                         all          TeX Live: LaTeX fundamental packages
ii  texlive-latex-extra                   2023.20240207-1                         all          TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages
ii  texlive-latex-recommended             2023.20240207-1                         all          TeX Live: LaTeX recommended packages
ii  texlive-pictures                      2023.20240207-1                         all          TeX Live: Graphics, pictures, diagrams
ii  texlive-plain-generic                 2023.20240207-1                         all          TeX Live: Plain (La)TeX packages
$
$ tlmgr init-usertree
$ tlmgr update --list
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2023) is older than remote repository (2024).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
$ tlmgr info multicol
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2023) is older than remote repository (2024).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
$

How can I install a specific version of multicol.sty LaTeX package without updating/breaking the others LaTeX packages already installed from texlive-latex-* DEB packages ?

A quick search tells that you need to install either of texlive-latex-extra or texlive-latex-base.
However, you can install texlive-full (it installs all available tex packages) and stop worrying about tex packages altogether. I have texlive-full installed, and I can compile .tex files with the multicol package in Ubuntu 24.04.

If you want the latest texlive, then first purge the system texlive packages,
sudo apt-get purge texlive*
sudo apt-get remove tex-common --purge

Install dependencies
sudo apt install wget perl-tk

Finally, install texlive
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar -xzf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
cd install-tl-version-number

For a specific version, e.g. texlive 2021,
sudo ./install-tl -repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2021/tlnet-final

Now, install
 sudo ./install-tl

Finally, add it to path,
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/doc/info${INFOPATH:+:${INFOPATH}}
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/doc/man${MANPATH:+:${MANPATH}}

Now, use equivs to make Ubuntu think that texlive is installed as a system package, so that it does not complain about dependencies
sudo apt install equivs --no-install-recommends freeglut3
wget -O debian-equivs-2023-ex.txt https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2023-ex.txt

Now install the dummy deb package
equivs-build debian-equivs-2023-ex.txt
sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_*.deb
sudo apt install -f

To install packages, run
sudo tlmgr --gui

Source

As you can see in the output of my dpkg -l | grep texlive- command, the texlive-latex-extra or texlive-latex-base packages were already installed so I already had the multicol.sty package but I need a different release of the multicol.sty package.

@SebMa In that case, you may want to replace your whole latex release with texlive 2024. Something like https://fahim-sikder.github.io/post/installing-texlive-latest-ubuntu/

@Archisman-Panigraphi Thanks a lot, can you please your last comment into your answer so I can accept it ?

@SebMa I edited the answer

@Archisman-Panigraphi Thanks. Can you also add a command line that enables to install a specific Texlive version, for example : sudo ./install-tl -repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2021/tlnet-final to your answer ?
